# OneDrive for Business disable "Always remove files" checkbox

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

We require our OneDrive users to [confirm large delete operations](https://admx.help/?Category=OneDrive&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.OneDriveNGSC::ForcedLocalMassDeleteDetection), to prevent shared libraries from being deleted accidentally.

However, there's a checkbox in the notification that can prevent this notification from being shown again:

[image: Remove files from all locations?]

We want to automatically uncheck the "Always remove files" checkbox if it is checked by the user. Does anyone know if there's a registry key where we can force the state of this checkbox?

Comment: [You can set an OneDrive Active Directory domain group policy to handle this behavior.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy)  It appears that `ForcedLocalMassDeleteDetection` if set to the enabled value will always prompt the user.

Comment: I do not find any settings related to "Always remove files" check box", it's recommended to check whether Ramhound's suggestion is helpful, that require users to confirm large delete operations.

Comment: Unfortunately Ramhounds' suggestion was not useful. That is the exact policy that we have applied (as linked in the OP). We're looking for a registry setting that controls the 'always remove files' checkbox in the prompt. If a user checks this box, the prompt doesn't come anymore, making the setting useless...